# How to fix xc_breakout error in RealityKit app?

Tags: swift, arkit, realitykit

I run this code, but always get an xc_breakout and don't know how to see error. I'm new in swift, so it may be simple stupid to solve it. I want to see some error, but it only shows xc_breakout. It happens in `Entity.load(contentsOf: destinationURL)` method

```
func loadModel() {
    let fileURL = URL(string: "serverUrlToDownloadUsdz")!
    let destinationURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent("file.usdz")
    
    let task = URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: fileURL) { (tempURL, response, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("error downloading: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }            
        guard let tempURL = tempURL else {
            print("temp file not found.")
            return
        }            
        do {
            if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: destinationURL.path) {
                try! FileManager.default.removeItem(at: destinationURL)
            }                
            try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: tempURL, to: destinationURL)
            print("saved at \(destinationURL)")
           
            do {
                let entity = try Entity.load(contentsOf: destinationURL)
                let model = Model(modelName: "file", modelEntity: entity)
                self.models.append(model)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }                
        } catch {
            print("error saving file: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }        
    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in this function add an breakpoint in print{"error"} lines and run the project then in debug session write po whatYouNeedToPrint . then you will get the output there and you can check what it is.

```
 do {
                let entity = try Entity.load(contentsOf: destinationURL)
                let model = Model(modelName: "file", modelEntity: entity)
                self.models.append(model)
                print("Model loaded successfully.")
            } catch {
                print("Error loading entity: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
```

update like this

Comment: it doesn't reach that line of code:(

Comment: then add breakpoint on or after or before that line

Comment: after all this if there any error occurs and you need to know about that printing the output or not in debugging area add an breakpoint in certain lines and run it

Comment: debug shows nothing, so I don't know what to solve

Comment: first of all you just clear all your breakpoints in your app and run the project.

Comment: replace your **print{error}** with  **print("Error loading entity: \(error.localizedDescription)"**  I have updated my answer look that and try once may be it will help you

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you set a breakpoint next to the following line:

[image]

All you have to do, is to delete it via RMB contextual menu.

[image]